# Warning equals/hashCode on Lombok's @Data annotation with inheritance

Tags: java, lombok

I have a entity which inherits from other. On other hand, I'm using Lombok project to reduce boilerplate code, so I put `@Data` annotation. The annotation `@Data` with inheritance produces the next warning:

> Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is intentional, add `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)` to your type.

I have the following questions:

- Is it advisable to add annotation `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)` or `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)`?
- If it is not added, which one is it: **`callSuper=false`** or
  **`callSuper=true`**?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

The [default value](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/EqualsAndHashCode.html#callSuper--) is `false`. That is the one you get if you don't specify it and ignore the warning.

Yes, it is recommended to add an `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation on the `@Data` annotated classes that extend something else than Object. I cannot tell you if you need `true` or `false`, that depends on your class hierarchy, and will need to be examined on a case-by-case basis.

However, for a project or package, you can configure in `lombok.config` to call the super methods if it is not a direct subclass of Object.

```
lombok.equalsAndHashCode.callSuper = call
```

See the [configuration system documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration.html) on how this works, and the [`@EqualsEndHashCode` documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html) for the supported configuration keys.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: Worked for me.  But just keep in mind that for the delombok plugin to pick this config file up it should be placed in the java source root directory, not in the resources directory, i.e. in src/main/java and not in src/main/resources

Comment: @Roel I'm wondering why the default is false. I would've expected the opposite. Also, is there an equivalent way to get toString() to call super by default? I see I can do "@ToString(callSuper=true)", but not seeing any such configuration setting. Thanks.

Comment: Does it matter if I add @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true) before or after @Data ?

Comment: @AnnaKlein the order doesn't matter

Answer (score 68):

`@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)` should resolve the warning.

Comment: This should be the accpeted answer since I don't think the suggestion of Roel should be done "lombok.equalsAndHashCode.callSuper = call" instead a decision for each class should be made.

Comment: @AnnaKlein I don't think so. In fact this answer should be a comment, there's no new information here, you can find that in my question. I did know `@EqualsAndHashCode` resolves the warning.

Comment: Actually per the accepted answer (and my answer below) you should choose between 'callSuper=true' or 'callSuper=false' in the annotation.

Answer (score 51):

The main original question is:

> Is it advisable to add annotation @EqualsAndHashCode (callSuper =
>   true) or @EqualsAndHashCode (callSuper = false)?

The accepted answer is basically just:

> ...that depends...

To expand on that, the documentation on [@EqualsAndHashCode](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) has some solid guidance on which to choose. Especially this, IMHO:

> By setting callSuper to true, you can include the equals and hashCode
>   methods of your superclass in the generated methods. For hashCode, the
>   result of super.hashCode() is included in the hash algorithm, and
>   forequals, the generated method will return false if the super
>   implementation thinks it is not equal to the passed in object. Be
>   aware that not all equals implementations handle this situation
>   properly. However, lombok-generated equals implementations do handle
>   this situation properly, so you can safely call your superclass equals
>   if it, too, has a lombok-generated equals method.

To distill this down a bit:
Chose 'callSuper=true' if you are inheriting from a superclass that either has no state information, or itself is using the @Data annotation, or has implementations of equals/hash that "handle the situation properly" - which I interpret to mean returning a proper hash of the state values.

Comment: I think this is the answer which well explains how to chose between callSuper = false and callSuper = true.

Comment: I agree. This explanation is really helpful.

Answer (score 29):

If you want to compare the members of the superclass as well, then use `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)`. If, however, you only want to compare fields in the current class you can use `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)` which is the **default** option.

If you use the *Delombok*-feature you can see that the difference is that when set to `true` this line is added to the generated *equals* method `if (!super.equals(o)) return false;`. If you have members in the superclass that should be taken into account when comparing two objects, then it has to be set to true to compare correctly.