# Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object

Tags: java, lombok

I am getting below error while using `lombok` and even it doesn't allow me to set id and version while creating `student` instance.

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - overrides com.example.demo.IModel.canEqual
    - Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is 
     intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.
    - overrides com.example.demo.IModel.hashCode
    - overrides com.example.demo.IModel.toString
    - overrides com.example.demo.IModel.equals
```

IModel

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class IModel {
    private String id;
    private String version;
}
```

Student

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student extends IModel{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

[image]

In the main method, it doesn't allow me to set the value of Id and version field

```
Student s = Student.builder().firstName("Adam").lastName("Kerr").build();
```

---

**Edit-1**
@sfiss - As suggested, now I changed like below, but now I am not able to set firstName and lastName, only cab set id and version

**Student.java**

```
@Data
@Builder(builderMethodName = "studentBuilder")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Student extends IModel {
    @NotEmpty(message = "{email.notempty}")
    @Email
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Student(final String firstName, final String lastName, final String id, final String version) {
        super(id, version);
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

IModel.java

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class IModel {
    private String id;
    private String version;
}
```

Comment: seems duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572566/warning-equals-hashcode-on-data-annotation-lombok-with-inheritance

Comment: I disagree (it is not a duplicate), this question also has the problem of using @Builder with inheritance. It is poorly named and apparantly the problem was not correctly identified by the OP.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There are multiple problems here, all of them relating to using lombok with inheritance:

1. > Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is 
   >    intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.

The warning is given by `@Data` because that usually generates equals/hashcode without the call to super. Fix it by adding `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)`.

2. The `@Builder` gives you a compile warning because it will generate two static methods with the same name in both the super- and the subclass. Fix it by defining `@Builder(builderMethodName = "studentBuilder")` on `Student`.
3. You won't be able to set superclass properties on you studentBuilder because your superclass and subclass have a default constructor. Fix it by creating a constructor and moving the `@Builder` annotation to it (i.e. *annotate the constructor with `@Builder`, not the class*):

Code:

```
@Builder(builderMethodName = "studentBuilder")
public Student(
    final String firstName,
    final String lastName,
    final String id,
    final String version) {
    super(id, version);
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Call your builder with the correct method (`IModel.builder()` vs `Student.studentBuilder()`):

```
Student.studentBuilder().firstName("Name").build();
```

---

I also want to add some improvements to the above solution. While I like lombok as a tool (I really don't need to *read* that much boilerplate), the first solution to preventing boilerplate is to think whether you need all those getters and setters and ask yourself these questions:

- Do you want bags of data? It is fine for some use cases, in others you want objects more in the sense of OOP, i.e. don't expose your state but behavior.
- Do you really need mutability? If not, prefer `@Value`.
- Do you really need both constructor types (especially the no-args-constructor)? They are part of the problem here. Sometimes you need them for frameworks (proxies, reflection, ...) to work properly.
- More specific to your code: You prefixed the superclass with "I" but it is not an interface. If it is meant as an abstract class, declare it `abstract` and don't give it a `@Builder`.

Comment: Thanks for great answer, however I am still facing issue, please refer EDIT-1

Comment: See my edited answer. In short: 1) use the correct builder factory method and 2) annotate the constructor that has alle the desired fields that you want in your builder.

Answer (score 9):

### The warning from building a Spring Boot project

When I built my Spring boot project, I got 20 warnings about a same thing. The warning shows: `Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass`

### Description of the warning

This warning is from lombook, it happens when we inherit a child class from parent class by using @Data @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode, IDE will trigger the warning: `Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass` .

### Solution

There are two solutions:

1. add annotation `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)` on the class
2. create lombook config file in the project root path: `src/main/java`. Note: this solution requires the version of lombook > 1.14.

I recommend the solution 2, since you will not need to add the annotation to all the required classes.

To impletement the solution, you need to create `lombok.config` in the path of `src/main/java`. If you have more than one packages, you may need to create multiple config files.

The content of the config file includes:

```
config.stopBubbling=true
lombok.equalsAndHashCode.callSuper=call
```

When we rebuild our project, you will not get these warnings anymore.

Cheers!

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [@sfiss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56583852/7927573) solution

or

You can use `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations instead of `@Data` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i resolved it **in this way** hope it helps you.
That **help** you **also** with **abstract classes**

**Student.java**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Student extends IModel {
    @NotEmpty(message = "{email.notempty}")
    @Email
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Builder
    public Student(final String firstName, final String lastName, final String id, final String version) {
        super(id, version);
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**IModel.java**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class IModel {
    private String id;
    private String version;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The error says  **If this is
intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.**

So, add `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)` to solve the problem.